# UIImageView in UITableCell shows in IB but not in Simulator?

Tags: swift

I have a weird problem. So I have a UIViewController with a UITableView/cell inside. Within each cell is a UIImageView. I'v added the image directly on the Interface Builder and the image shows.

But, when I test the app live on the simulator or my iPhone the UIImageview does not appear.

Would love to see if any of you have ideas on why. Please check out images below!

Thank you all very much

(I need 10 rep to post images so i linked them..if thats against the rules im sorry but i didnt know how else to show you the problem!)

[image][image]

```
import UIKit

class freeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var aName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var aDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var aImage: UIImageView!



}

class FreeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var sharedDataApp = SharedDataApp.sharedInstanceApp

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

    }

    // MARK: UITableView method implementation

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sharedDataApp.parsedArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("freeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! freeCell

    var s = self.sharedDataApp.parsedArray[indexPath.row]
    var i = s["thumbnail_url"] as! String // Prints Image URL
    cell.aName.text = s["name"] as? String
    if let imgURL = NSURL(string: "\(i)") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL) {
            cell.aImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            print(imgURL)

        }
    }
    //cell.aImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    cell.aDescription.text = s["public_name"] as? String

    return cell


}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't set up the data source of uitableview in your viewController.please post the code of your UIViewController

Comment: did you set the autolayout constraints of the tableview cell? if you have set in the any size class image may go outside the frame

Comment: Well If i add the image to UIImageView in IB..it shows in every cell. But if i set it programmatically it does not show.. weird!

Answer (score 2):

Do these while working with `tableview`

1. set datasource and delegate first
2. and give proper outlets
3. and implement `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method properly
4. and check wether your cell's height is proper

Comment: Ok I have added the view controller code above. So if i set the UIImageView source in the Interface Builder..the image shows in each cell. But if I set it programmatically (like i have in the code above) it does not show...

Comment: If you are adding it programatically then check that imageview's position is proper in that cell or not and you have to implement heightForRowAtIndexpath method of tableview and set proper height of that cell

Comment: It looks you are setting image from url..right? Then you have to  use below code ...if let imgUrl = NSURL(string: "http://greentreesarborcareinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/image-placeholder.jpg") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        cell.aImage.image= UIImage(data: data)
    }        
}

Comment: I added the UIImageView in IB and then connected it to the TableCell. Also I added your code as you can see above but the image still doesnt show. If I add the image directly from IB (The image is in Assets.xcassets) it will show.

Comment: yes but if you want to download image from url you have to use code that I wrote

Comment: Yes as you can see above I have implemented it but in simulator or iPhone it does not work..

Comment: check autolayyout constraints are proper or not?

Comment: Yes because when i set Image in Interface Builder for the UIImageView it shows in simulator and iPhone. Check - http://imgur.com/b0gUqaG

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why.

These are the steps I took.

1. Opened my Projects info.plist file Added a Key called
2. NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.
3. Added a Subkey called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its
   value to YES as like following image.